# Retrieving a range of items from a MongoDB capped collection in natural order

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to retrieve a range of items in a capped collection when the _id field is more or less random?

Say we have create a simple capped collection like:

```
> db.createCollection("capped_test", {capped: true, size: 1048576})
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: 512, v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: 111, v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: 316, v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: 983, v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: 326, v: "test"})
```

What I'm looking to do is retrieve the documents in natural order from _id: 111 to _id: 983. If I try something like:

```
> db.capped_test.find({_id: {$gte: 111, $lte: 983}}).sort({$natural: 1})
```

I get all of the documents, (which makes sense as all the id's fall within this range)

```
{ "_id" : 512, "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : 111, "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : 316, "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : 983, "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : 326, "v" : "test" }
```

What I'm looking for is a query that will yield:

```
{ "_id" : 111, "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : 316, "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : 983, "v" : "test" }
```

Is this possible?

My actual use case involves many clients writing to a single capped collection. Periodicity, I'd like to fire off a map reduce job that calculates some aggregates on the data that was added since the last map reduce job was run. As such, a query object that I could pass as an option to db.collection.mapReduce() would be useful.

**Edit:**

To clarify, the same issue would seem to exist when using ObjectID's and you have multiple clients writing to the same collection. Given that an ObjectID is made of `ObjectId("ttttttttmmmmmmppppcccccc")` where t is the timestamp, m is the machine id, p is the process id, c is the counter, we can simulate multiple clients inserting docs all within the same timestamp:

```
> db.createCollection("capped_test", {capped: true, size: 1048576})
{ "ok" : 1 }
>
> // Client with machine id 1 writes
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: ObjectId("000000010000010000000000"), v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: ObjectId("000000010000010000000001"), v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: ObjectId("000000010000010000000002"), v: "test"})
>
> // Client with machine id 2 writes
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: ObjectId("000000010000020000000000"), v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: ObjectId("000000010000020000000001"), v: "test"})
>
> // Client with mahcine id 1 writes again
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: ObjectId("000000010000010000000003"), v: "test"})
> db.capped_test.insert({_id: ObjectId("000000010000010000000004"), v: "test"})
```

Querying all docs between the second and second to last documents:

```
> db.capped_test.find({_id: {$gte: ObjectId("000000010000010000000001"), $lte: ObjectId("000000010000010000000003")}}).sort({$natural: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000010000000001"), "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000010000000002"), "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000010000000003"), "v" : "test" }
```

When the desired result would be:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000010000000001"), "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000010000000002"), "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000020000000000"), "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000020000000001"), "v" : "test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000010000010000000003"), "v" : "test" }
```

Comment: is this your actual document schema or might you be using other fields?  Does _id have to be something provided by you or could it be MongoDB's ObjectId()?

Comment: there is a way to do this but I'm wondering, how will you know where to start?  Will the previous map/reduce job record somewhere the last record it processed?

Comment: The _id, as I'm currently using it in the capped collection is actually an object of three other fields which uniquely describe that document. I say "more or less random", because none of those fields have anything to do with the insert order. I considered using a ObjectID so I could make use of the inherent timestamp, but the next part of the ObjectID is a machine id. Considering that I have ~10 clients generating ~500 inserts a second, I could potentially loose some some documents or duplicate others as the timestamp only has 1 second resolution.

Comment: that's a misunderstanding of ObjectId() you would not generate a duplicate as there are 3 bytes at the end dedicated to a counter so within the same second from same machine and same pid you would get room for over 16M IDs generated. :)   So your concern about duplicates is misplaced here.